# Statistics for ratio of questions to answers

Tags: discussion

It seems some people have a ton of questions on Stack Overflow, but relatively few answers, whereas some people have a ton of answers but relatively few questions; it seems like a smaller percentage of people fall in the "even" category.

I can't find a graph/grid of these ratios. Is this particular metric available somewhere?

I'm looking for a histogram of number of answers/number of questions.

```
 
     |#
    U|##
    S|###
    E|#####
    R|#########
    S|#############
     |------------------
            #A/#Q
```

Comment: You should be able to make a query with [the Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries) that returns such a ration. Maybe there is such a query listed already.

Comment: It is not clear exactly what statistics you are after. Could you please elaborate? Is http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/52131/reputation-to-post-ratio close to what you are looking for?

Comment: @N.N. I updated the post

Comment: The query [User Counts of ratio of answer to question](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/64321/user-counts-of-ratio-of-answer-to-question) which calculates the ratio and then counts the number of users in each ratio, may help you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the data from [User Counts of ratio of answer to question Rounded to the nearest integer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/64322/user-counts-of-ratio-of-answer-to-question-rounded-to-the-nearest-integer)

I created this pie chart and you're correct. Less than 25% of users that have a question or answer* have a ratio near 1 or greater.

[image]

<sup>*Users with no answers or questions are not represented on this graph. [They are actually almost as big](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/64323/users-that-have-neither-a-question-or-answer) as the "questions but no answers group"</sup>

Comment: -1, I don't know what this circular... thing... is, but it's certainly not a histogram! Okay, seriously though, question about your labeling: would ratio of 0.25 fall under "r~1," or are multiple-questions-per-answer users included in the thinner, unlabeled slices?

Comment: .25 rounds to 0 so it falls into the "questions but no answer" group. This does indeed skew the data significantly. Here's the same pie chart but rounded to two [decimal places](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cn9wf.jpg). This means that there's more than 25% of users have a ratio of .01 or greater.

Comment: EXCELLENT! Just what I was looking for.