# The ratio of people who ask questions / people who answer questions

Tags: discussion

Are there any statistics about how many people ask  questions and how many people answer to those questions?

My gut feeling is that there are much less people answering the questions, but I'd like to have some evidence backing this up.

Comment: You could get those stats from the [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/); bin people in 'askers' and 'answerers' based on their post type ratios.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125785/statistics-for-ratio-of-questions-to-answers

Comment: Are you only interested in people that *only answer* vs people that *only ask*?

Comment: @AzizShaikh: Thanks! That's what I am looking for.